# Single Sign On (Silent Login) using iframe and postMessage while ITP (Safari)

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, safari, single-sign-on

Short:

I need help in SSO in Safari, I'm using iFrame and postMessage logic which is working fine in Chrome and Firefox (PC, Mac, Android and iOS) but the catch is in Safari. I tried Storage Access APIs and placed those in iFrame's onLoading event to check access. But the localStorage which I was used to store JWT is not persistent in the iFrame. I'm using Angular 11.

Scenario:

I'm developing few applications which uses same auth site for sso, which was working as expected as I said in short description. But when it comes to Intelligent Tracking Prevention enabled browsers as of now Safari, It blocks the iFrame by considering it as 3rd Party Trackers which is very insane since the iFrame's origin (Domain) is same with Sub-domain used in service sites.

I tried to check the access by using storage access API i.e hasStorageAccess() in window onLoad method in the iFrame's script. If has no access, I called requestStorageAccess(). I'm here not using user gesture and using button click from service site because I'm using angular for frontend framework but in order to request using button in iFrame.(Since, The policy specifies to get access works only after user interaction which is another headache for devs)

I need help to overcome this issue and fix the SSO with ITP. Any guidance is useful and I'll keep updated.

Google is working fine with their sso and services such as YouTube and Mail doesn't need login on every visit. Any idea on how they achieved.

Comment: Hey. I’m facing the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be that Safari has the option "*Prevent cross-site tracking"* enabled by default and that can interfere with the SSO login and display of an embedded iframe (because it blocks some cookies).

**Solution**

Disable (uncheck) the option for "Prevent cross-site tracking" in the Safari configuration menu.

[image]

**Tip**: To achieve a better user experience, using Javascript you can detect when a user is using Safari and show him an HTML message explaining that he needs to disable that option in order to continue or use another browser like Chrome or Firefox.